# Clojure. Intellij. Delay. Concurrent. Clojure from the Ground Up

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, java.util.concurrent, cursive

I'm trying to solve the Exercises at the end of Chapter 6 of *Clojure From the Ground Up*.
Here's what happens to me on the Very First Problem there...

```
  (defn sum [start end] (delay (reduce + (range start end))))  ;; Define sum.
=> #'chapter6.core/sum

  (time (sum 0 1e7))  ;; Start sum but it delays, so almost no time elapses.
"Elapsed time: 0.2808 msecs"
=> #object[clojure.lang.Delay 0x2656db01 {:status :pending, :val nil}]

  (deref sum)  ;; Ask for the result. This should take some time. Only it doesn't. It errors right away.

Execution error (ClassCastException) at chapter6.core/eval1595 (form-init10872915734268438705.clj:1).
class chapter6.core$sum cannot be cast to class java.util.concurrent.Future (chapter6.core$sum is in unnamed module of loader cloju-re.lang.DynamicClassLoader @7c650722; java.util.concurrent.Future is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I'm new. I know nothing of "bootstrap" or "module" or...
What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.
BTW, is there a "...From The Ground Up" Answer Key for the Exercises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it:

```
(deref (sum 0 1e7))
```

Your function only returns a delay *when it's called*. In `(deref sum)`, nothing calls it (and, indeed, you never provide argument values would would be mandatory to include *were* it called). Rather, you try to deref the function `sum` itself, which is illegal, because a function is not a delay.

Comment: Tried this before I submitted this question. Here's what I got:

Comment: (deref (sum))
Execution error (ArityException) at chapter6.core/eval1609 (form-init10872915734268438705.clj:1).
Wrong number of args (0) passed to: chapter6.core/sum

Comment: And as for being "blindingly obvious," to me, it makes NO SENSE that I should have to call the 'sum' function TWICE with the same arguments. What if I should call it first with (sum 0 1e7) and then (deref (sum 0 1e8))? I guess I'll go back to the REPL and find out what happens. Thanks for your help. I'm truly grateful.

Comment: You *don't* need to call it first with `(sum 0 1e7)`.

Comment: ...basically, a bare `(sum 0 1e7)` just *returns* a delay, but if you never deref that delay, the work doesn't get done. I assume what the book is telling you to do at the REPL  is just looking at the return value to *see* that it's a delay being returned; then, running it again and actually dereffing the delay returned by the second call. But the first call doesn't do any kind of hidden state change or such; it's just informational.

Comment: Every time you execute `(sum 0 1e7)` you get a new coupon that you can redeem - with `deref` - for the result. Normally you would put the coupon into a variable, e.g., `(let [p (sum 0 1e7)] ...)` where the body of the let may make zero or more uses of `@p`.  The possibility of zero uses is a main reason for using `delay`, to avoid the cost of computation unless the result is called for.

Comment: Tanks, da bodda uz. (as we say in Chicago)

Answer (score -1):

The details are easier to see if you create a project rather than running in the REPL.  Consider adding your code to [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.misc :as misc]))

(defn sum
  [start end]
  (delay (reduce + (range start end))))  ;; Define sum.

(dotest
  (time (sum 0 1e7)) ;; Start sum but it delays, so almost no time elapses.
  (let [delay-val (sum 0 1e7)] ; sum returns a delay
    (spyxx delay-val)               ; print name & type of `delay-val`
    (time (deref delay-val))        ; `deref` forces the computation of the sum
    (spyxx (deref delay-val))       ; print expression & type
    ))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

"Elapsed time: 0.140221 msecs"      ; from first `time`
delay-val => <#clojure.lang.Delay #object[clojure.lang.Delay 0x455cd186 {:status :pending, :val nil}]>

"Elapsed time: 189.021064 msecs"    ; from 2nd `time`
(deref delay-val) => <#java.lang.Long 49999995000000>
```

There are more docs [in the README](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging) and the [API docs](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.198/doc/readme).

---

Try adding:

```
(spyxx sum)
```

which produces:

```
sum => <#tst.demo.core$sum #object[tst.demo.core$sum 0x539edd3 "tst.demo.core$sum@539edd3"]>
```

This is how Clojure "prints" the value of a function.

---

If you make a mistake, you can get a line number in the error msg that helps greatly. It is not legal to deref a function, so we get an error:

```
(deref sum)   ; on line #17 of my file
```

produces:

```
ERROR in (dotest-line-9) (core.clj:2298)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: class tst.demo.core$sum cannot be cast to class java.util.concurrent.Future (tst.demo.core$sum is in unnamed module of loader clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader @67af3485; java.util.concurrent.Future is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at clojure.core$deref_future.invokeStatic (core.clj:2298)
    clojure.core$deref.invokeStatic (core.clj:2320)
    clojure.core$deref.invoke (core.clj:2306)
    tst.demo.core$fn__21007.invokeStatic (core.clj:17) # ***** error line number *****
    tst.demo.core/fn (core.clj:9)
    clojure.test$test_var$fn__9737.invoke (test.clj:717)
    clojure.test$test_var.invokeStatic (test.clj:717)
    <...snip...>
```

---

**Update**

Don't forget to include this line in your `project.clj` under `:dependencies`:

```
 [tupelo "0.9.198"]
```

See [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) for an example.

Comment: Don't have your testing libraries. Executing

Comment: (ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.misc :as misc]))

Comment: gives me:  Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at tst.demo.core/eval1623$loading (form-init10872915734268438705.clj:1).
Could not locate tupelo/core__init.class, tupelo/core.clj or tupelo/core.cljc on classpath.